# C++ Pass by Reference and Value and Const Issues

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have the following general code, where I have a class which implements a view on some memory and this can be created in various ways. It is used to provide a consistent interface for some data processing functions.

```
class CView
{
    ...
    int m_size;
    float *m_data;
};

class CObjectA
{
    ...
    CView m_view;

    const CView View() const { return m_view; } // returned
    CView View() { return m_view; } // returned
};

class CObjectB
{
    ...
    const CView View() const { return CView(.....); } // constructed
    CView View() { return CView(.....); } // constructed
};

void ProcessAdd(CView &dst, const CView &src1, const CView &src2);
void ProcessReverse(CView &dst, const CView &src);
void ProcessMul(CView &dst, const CView &src1, const CView &src2);
```

Now I'm wondering if the `View` methods should be returning by reference or value, and also whether the `Process` method should be using references or values. I want to minimize copying but keep the ability to do something like:

```
CObjectA a1, a2;
CObjectB b1;
... init these somehow
ProcessAdd(a1.View(), b1.View(), a2.View());
```

It seems that the compiler does not allow me to make the View() methods return a copy and then pass by reference into the `Process` functions.

The `View` object is fairly light weight and just points to data that can be read or modified.

If the `View` methods return a `CView` instead of a `CView &` type, does this mean that there will be double copying when I pass these into the `Process` function? What is the most efficient way of getting the desired behavior?

The other issue is what is the right way of implementing const correctness? I actually never want the process functions to change the member variables of the `CView` class, but I do want the data pointer in the `CView` class to be pointing to non-const data for the first parameter of `Process` which is the output view. If I pass by value presumably there is no point in having a const qualifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that if you're passing by value, there's no need to make it a `const` value.

To answer the first part of your question, if you return a `CView` and pass it into the process functions, it will not be copied again because the `ProcessAdd`, `ProcessReverse`, and `ProcessMul` functions' arguments are all references. It will use the same `CView` objects that were passed.

There are some cleaner approaches that may make sense for your application if you want to encapsulate the `CView` objects. For example, you could change your view methods to look like this:

```
const CView& View() const { return m_view; }
```

Then you could leave the Process functions alone if you have other references to views that you want to modify. However, since it looks like you're creating new objects that combine the other `CView`s, you can change the functions to return a new view directly:

```
CView ProcessAdd(const CView &src1, const CView &src2);
```

Could you pass all of your `CView`s by value? Probably. The type you have in your example is small, so the copies probably wouldn't make that much of a difference. If the objects have any important pointer ownership rules (which it looks like they might) or could be expanded to have more information, however, then you probably want to just use references from the start.

Comment: If the Process functions arguments are passed by value will the `CView` objects be copied twice: once in the `View` method and once at the function call, or is the compiler smart enough not to do that?

Comment: @Robotbugs That's a really good question. I'm not sure if that's defined in the C++ standard or not, or if it's left undefined.

Comment: @Robotbugs Do you have an example? The standard allows implementations to elide copies in various situations, and this is well implemented on most popular compiler/platform combinations. But the devil is in the details, as they way.

Comment: @Robotbugs Also, if you return a value, usually it means you can make that method `const` (unless it needs to call non-const methods to create the value.) So in your case, you would only need a single `View()` method, `CView View() const;`, not the two you have shown.

Comment: Actually I believe the two `View` methods are necessary, even if it returns a value. This is because I want it to return a const object if the class is const and a non const object if not. The constness of the `View` object is intended to indicate not only that the `View` members cannot be changed but also that the underlying memory is read only. I did not show it here but access methods on the `View` object that allow you to get at the data return a const float reference if the `View` is const and a float reference if not. Thus preventing assignment to the memory elements if `View` is const.